# putting validation properties on $this->Js->Submit

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have this ajax submit button in my view and I want to validate the fields when it is being clicked. What specific properties am i going to apply for this action?

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Save Post', array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#success',
    'id' => 'btnSubmit',
    ));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write direct jQuery validation to the fields. No need to attach that to the JSHelper. If you want to have server side validation. You can call the `$this->ModelName->validates()` method.